# Sign out the user

Tags: android, google-plus

[Here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user) in the code sample provided by Google the connect method is called directly after the disconnect method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
  }
}
```

This code snippets as discribed should be used to sign user out of Google+. why they reconnect again?

**Is that code sample wrong? if not what is the explanation and what the connect method really do if not sign in?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are immediately connecting it after disconnecting

```
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
mGoogleApiClient.connect(); #Remove this part
```

It's a mistake in their site.

Comment: This is not my code its google's code from the link. Is that code that google provided wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is, wrong. It is not a mistake. When you signout from `Google plus`, you are presented with the option of choosing another or same account again. That's why `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` is called again after you've disconnected.It doesn't automatically sign you back in, it just asks for you to choose an account to resign in with.

Comment: I just added two google accounts to my device. Even that when using the code snippets disconnecting then connecting it does;t ask the user to choose the account. it connects with the old account automatically without any user interaction. It stay a tutorial mistake don't you think?

Comment: in order to allow the user to choose account you need to clear the default account. Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient); and that not there in the disconnect connect code snippet

Comment: The tutorial you are following is quite old.Not that it is not correct.`clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()` is the new method. take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html)

Comment: Aha, great thank you for the clarification. then they should also update the documentation or remove it. it still wrong :)

Comment: Haha.They always take their time updating documentations.